# What does "moving" mean in Google Location History?

Tags: google-maps, google-location-history

While reviewing my phone location on https://maps.google.com/locationhistory, I see some locations where I know the information is right. There are other times though that Google Maps says my phone was "Moving" but doesn't say where it started, where it finished, or offer an explanation. Furthermore, I don't recall going anywhere at those times.

What is wrong? What does "Moving" mean to Google (does it mean moving a few feet, does it mean changing WiFi networks, does it mean connecting to a different cell tower)?

Comment: I would guess that it means that it couldn't get a GPS lock, but the accelerometer indicated motion.  I don't actually know though.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I guess what makes me uncertain is if I am at a known location for at least 15 minutes why would be accelerometer kick in and say that my phone is moving?

Answer (score 0):

if a location is modified in any way, it will say moving. I.e. if you change location name or time, any modifications made means moving. Try it!